# how to access nested values inside json object inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, url

I have this URL which returns me a JSON value, my task is to access 3 values out of it that is name, title and ISBN.

Since the content is heavily nested, I am not able to access the values inside it.

All the tutorials I have referred so far, have simple nesting in them

I have attached my code that I have written so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var globalJsonVar;
  alert("check");
  $.getJSON("https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:9781606868829&jscmd=details&format=json", function(result) {
    if (Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
      alert("conetnt is present");
      console.log(result);
      alert(Object.values(result));
      alert(result.ISBN: 9781606868829. bib_key); // my attempt at accessing the values
    } else {
      alert("hoax");
    }
  });
});
```

The JSON content that I am receiving is

```js
{
  "ISBN:9780143039648": {
    "bib_key": "ISBN:9780143039648",
    "preview": "noview",
    "preview_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL17924003M/The_guide",
    "info_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL17924003M/The_guide",
    "details": {
      "number_of_pages": 196,
      "series": [
        "Penguin classics"
      ],
      "lc_classifications": [
        "PR9499.3.N3 G85 2006"
      ],
      "latest_revision": 7,
      "uri_descriptions": [
        "Contributor biographical information",
        "Publisher description"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "Fiction."
      ],
      "title": "The guide",
      "languages": [{
        "key": "/languages/eng"
      }],
      "subjects": [
        "Malgudi (India : Imaginary place) -- Fiction.",
        "Tour guides (Persons) -- Fiction.",
        "Bharata natyam dancers -- Fiction.",
        "Spiritual life -- Hinduism -- Fiction.",
        "India -- Fiction."
      ],
      "publish_country": "nyu",
      "by_statement": "R.K. Narayan ; introduction by Michael Gorra.",
      "type": {
        "key": "/type/edition"
      },
      "uris": [
        "http://www.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0716/2006044314-b.html",
        "http://www.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0716/2006044314-d.html"
      ],
      "revision": 7,
      "publishers": [
        "Penguin Books"
      ],
      "dewey_decimal_class": [
        "823/.914"
      ],
      "last_modified": {
        "type": "/type/datetime",
        "value": "2012-08-05T21:10:58.887826"
      },
      "key": "/books/OL17924003M",
      "authors": [{
        "name": "Rasipuram Krishnaswamy Narayan",
        "key": "/authors/OL5911201A"
      }],
      "publish_places": [
        "New York"
      ],
      "oclc_number": [
        "65644730"
      ],
      "pagination": "xxiv, 196 p. ;",
      "created": {
        "type": "/type/datetime",
        "value": "2008-10-07T19:30:19.584308"
      },
      "url": [
        "http://www.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0716/2006044314-b.html",
        "http://www.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0716/2006044314-d.html"
      ],
      "notes": {
        "type": "/type/text",
        "value": "Originally published: New York : Viking Press, 1958.\n\nIncludes bibliographical references (p. [xxi]-xxii)."
      },
      "identifiers": {
        "goodreads": [
          "129877"
        ],
        "librarything": [
          "6930"
        ]
      },
      "isbn_13": [
        "9780143039648"
      ],
      "lccn": [
        "2006044314"
      ],
      "isbn_10": [
        "0143039644"
      ],
      "publish_date": "2006",
      "works": [{
        "key": "/works/OL1057183W"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with `result["ISBN:9781606868829"].bib_key`

Comment: You already have the ISBN as you make the request with it, and `title` and `name` appear to be the same thing...?

Comment: You can use the 'dot operator` (`.`) for named values and the square bracket with numbers for items in an array. So `console.log` accesses the function at `log` inside the object named `console`.  `fruits[0]` would return the first item in the array fruits.  You can also put strings/variables between brackets-- so `console["log"]` would also work.

Comment: I inserted this inside the alert statement , and i got the same reply , i.e, `ISBN:9781606868829`

Comment: Please use 4 space tabbing in all posts to achieve code clarity and minimize horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @mickmackusa ... what's wrong with a 2 space indentation?!

Comment: @mickmackusa SO uses the Google code tidier library which uses 2 spaces for tabs to fill as much code as possible in the horizontal space.

Comment: @HarjeevSingh `result['ISBN:9780143039648'].bib_key` contains the ISBN number.

Comment: @mickmackusa - a simple TIDY before saving a snippet and then removal of the top line to not make it a snippet was enough. We do not want no filthy tabs

Comment: My comment, from the review queue, was posted while the code had ~20 space indentation. I don't mind 2 space indentation.

Comment: @lumio . Thank you . i am able to access title now . going to access author now.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `[]` if you want to have access to keys that have special chars, for example `result['something-with:special-chars']`

Answer (score -1):

```
result.ISBN:9781606868829.bib_key
```

is a syntax error. `:` is not allowed here. You want to use the following syntay :

```
result["ISBN:9781606868829"].bib_key
```

Comment: Should you not look for dupe and close it?

Comment: So now we get downvotes when posting good answers. I'm wondering how to make some rep on SO nowadays. Everything is a duplicate, and when we answer it anyways, we get downvoted. Why didn't _you_ vote to close it instead?

Comment: i tried this approach . it did'nt work out

Comment: @JeremyThille i already voted to close but net seems to be intermittent. Also point is, we should try to reduce content duplications. So for that, we should not answer basic questions. You will find questions worth answering, but gaining rep from answering same thing 10 times will not do any good. Rep does not count much in real world. It's knowledge that is important

Comment: Oh I totally agree, I'm just trying to reach 10k :) For the fun